# Squish test: get active or top window by Squish

Tags: python, qt, automation, squish

I am creating automation tests using Squish, application depends on hardware, so I cannot kill application from processes because it is not good for hardware. When test cases are failed, the script just clicks the Shutdown button. But I don't know the state of application in advance and the Shutdown button could be obscured by other windows, so I need to find the top or active window and close it first.

Is there any way to find the top or active window in Squish?
I am using python for Qt application.

Comment: Found a solution. I used `QApplication.activeWindow()`.

Comment: That aside, there is also [ToplevelWindow.focused()](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#ToplevelWindow.focused-function).